# GNU Parallel does not run on all files

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I am using GNU Parallel to run the same command on multiple files in a directory. Using the example provided in the documentation, I use

```
find input -name *.json -print0 | parallel -0 "context --file={} --result={/.}.pdf sometex.tex"
```

This command allows me to produce a pdf file for every json file in the directory. However, when I run this, I get different results every time. Out of 1000 json files, some times I get 490 pdf files, some times I get 800. I have also tried running the command sequentially, and running sequentially was able to produce all 1000 pdf files. Does anyone know why this happens and how do I solve it?

Comment: If you don't have too many files, use `parallel command ::: input/*.json`

Comment: If you do have too many, use `find input -name \*.json -print0 | parallel -0 command` or similar.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, thanks so much for your answer! I've tried both of them, but I can't seem to get the same number of files all the time (like some runs produce 700, some runs produce 400). Do you know any more deterministic way?

Comment: Please state your OS. Please identify if any errors occur. Please try repeatedly running `find input -name \*.json | wc -l` and `find input -name \*.json -printf "." | wc -c`

Comment: I'm using RHEL 8.3 as my OS. I repeatedly tried those commands and got 1000 every time, but my command works a variable number of times.

Comment: Ok, I think you'll need to edit your question and show the actual command you are using.

Comment: Yup, I think to share more context, the exact command I'm using is 

`find input -name \*.json -print0 | parallel -0 "context --file={} --result={/.}.pdf sometex.tex"`

When I run this, I get different number of pdfs produced. However, I am pretty sure that the command will work individually because I have also tried a sequential implementation done in a for loop.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your original question and add your code in there and format it correctly. Also, try removing the double quotes in your command.

Comment: Yes, I've also tried running without the double quotes, but there's no difference

Comment: At the two `=` signs in your command, try enclosing everything that follows in `"`, i.e. `file="{}"` and the other one.

Comment: Yup, I've just tried that, but the number of files produced is different again. I was wondering if this could be due to some other issue besides the command?

Comment: Mmm, try `... | parallel --dry-run ... > file.txt` and then count the lines in `file.txt` and try loading it into an editor and seeing if you can find what's going wrong.

Comment: Oh, this actually returns 1000 lines. Could this be due to a failure when actually running the commands? But with the differing number of pdfs created in different runs, I do not think there's any issue with the command and files themselves, but maybe something else

Comment: Maybe you have `input/A/fred.json` and `input/B/fred.json` which will collide when creating the output file.

Comment: Oh no, there isn't such a case. Currently my files are called file_0.json to file_999.json. But following your comment, maybe I can try calling them more differing names instead and experiment. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

After doing some investigation, I realise the issue is not with GNU Parallel but because I was trying to access the same file when using this command

```
find input -name *.json -print0 | parallel -0 "context --file={} --result={/.}.pdf sometex.tex"
```

This probably led to a race condition. I solved this my making a copy of the .tex file for each input and things were able to run smoothly.